# GPS Exact coordinates - android?

Tags: java, gps, latitude-longitude, android-gps

I am using GPS to get latitude and longitude of user when is walking, but when I get coordinates (latitude and longitude), they are with 2 or 3 meter distance difference.

How can I have the exact coordinates ?

I am writing my app with Android Studio.

Comment: In my minds, GPS has a precision of 10 meter when no moving (DGPS which equips modern receiver can have 5 to 3 meter of precision. Best of DGPS can have 10cm, but I doubt they equip a lot of standard equipments). Precision of (D)GPS decreases when velocity increses. So, for me, it simply impossible to get such precision with standard equipments

Comment: What can I do ?

Comment: For example I am walking on sidewalk but when I see the result on map it show me in houses .

Comment: Garf365 already said, this can happen due to the imprecision of GPS. The only thing you can do, build your own satellite and make your own GPS system or find if there are systems that are more accurate on the market

Comment: I had also precision given are in best case, ie no cloud, no rain, no relief, no building...

Comment: @ Garf365 . Can I use from DGPS in android ?